# How to cast SilverStripe variable in Controller extension

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have the following code:

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController
{
    public function TimeNow() {
        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

But the following template code doesn't work:

```html
$TimeNow.Format(Ymd\THis)
```

I'm guessing this is because `TimeNow` isn't cast as an [`SS_Datetime`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SS_Datetime.html) object (which inherits the `Format` method).

How do I cast `TimeNow` as `SS_Datetime`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
public function TimeNow() {
    return SS_DateTime::now();
}
```

Comment: Can that be used to cast any sort of variable? i.e. `return SS_DateTime::(strtotime($this->DateTime)+3600);`

Comment: No. `strtotime` is a built in PHP function, not a static method on the SS_DateTime class. `now` returns an `SS_DateTime object`, and `format()` is inherited from the parent class. See https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.4.0/model/fieldtypes/Datetime.php#L175